Why use cData in Turnstile
In the configurations section for Cloudflare Turnstile, they list a cData (or data-cdata) option:

A customer payload that can be used to attach customer data to the challenge throughout its issuance and which is returned upon validation.

I am having trouble thinking of why & when such a parameter would be used. Why include some data here rather than in your eventual API call when you send the Turnstile token header?
At first I thought it was to create a non-standard setup to make it harder for those using captcha-solving services, but I see that those services include this parameter in their API.
Why else would one use this parameter?

Did you figure it out? Wondering this myself.

no, did not figure it out so far
